# Limit Dropdown from JSON File

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to parse my JSON file into a selectbox but i want only one value being in the drop down, not duplicates of the same KEY.

```
{
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "CTS SPORTS WAGON MANUAL V8 RWD SUPERCHARGED",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "S/WAGON",
    "crsp": 5280463.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "CTS V WAGON MANUAL V8 RWD SUPERCHARGED",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "S/WAGON",
    "crsp": 8767560.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "STS MANUAL V8 AWD",
    "engine_capacity": 3600.0,
    "body_type": "SAL",
    "crsp": 6507501.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "DTS AUTO V8",
    "engine_capacity": 4600.0,
    "body_type": "SAL",
    "crsp": 6424919.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "SRX CROSSOVER FWD AUTO MANUAL V6",
    "engine_capacity": 3000.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 4764322.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE V8 AWD AUTO",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 8733788.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE HYBRID AUTO 2WD SFI RWD HYBRID",
    "engine_capacity": 6000.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 10203756.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE ESV AUTO V8 AWD",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 9095086.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE EXT AUTO V8 AWD",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 8555347.0
  }
```

In this case i just want `car_make` to be one in the dropdown so that cadillac doesnt appear multiple times, hope you get what am trying to ask. I trying to use Javascript and flask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mix of [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to get the unique `car_make`s:

```js
let data = [{
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "CTS SPORTS WAGON MANUAL V8 RWD SUPERCHARGED",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "S/WAGON",
    "crsp": 5280463.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "CTS V WAGON MANUAL V8 RWD SUPERCHARGED",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "S/WAGON",
    "crsp": 8767560.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "STS MANUAL V8 AWD",
    "engine_capacity": 3600.0,
    "body_type": "SAL",
    "crsp": 6507501.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "DTS AUTO V8",
    "engine_capacity": 4600.0,
    "body_type": "SAL",
    "crsp": 6424919.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "SRX CROSSOVER FWD AUTO MANUAL V6",
    "engine_capacity": 3000.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 4764322.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE V8 AWD AUTO",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 8733788.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE HYBRID AUTO 2WD SFI RWD HYBRID",
    "engine_capacity": 6000.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 10203756.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE ESV AUTO V8 AWD",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 9095086.0
  },
  {
    "car_make": "CADILLAC",
    "model": "ESCALADE EXT AUTO V8 AWD",
    "engine_capacity": 6200.0,
    "body_type": "SUV",
    "crsp": 8555347.0
  }
];

let result = data
  .map(item => item.car_make)
  .filter((item, index, array) => {
    return array.indexOf(item) === index;
  });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks that was pretty helpful. Got me out of a cyclic bind.